# Why can any homeomorphism on a topological space can be extended to its Čech-Stone compactification?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, compactness, open-map, compactification

Let $X$ be a topological space.

More times, I came across the statement that the Čech-Stone compactification (the "most general" compactification of a topological space) **clearly** has a property that any homeomorphism on the original space can be extended onto the compactification. Why is that clear though? How do we check that homeomorphisms can be extended?

My idea would be:

1. Take homeomorphism on the original space
2. Define the homeomorphism on the remainder (what was "added" to the space to create the $\beta X$ compactification)

Am I right? Could you provide some examples of particular homeomorphisms and how to construct the extension? (I don´t mean the simplest cases as adding just one infinity point to the original space, but something more interesting, ideally for the Čech-Stone compactification).

Comment: This is a decent question.  The simplest answer is that $\beta$ is functorial, so it necessarily preserves homeomorphims.  That is not entirely satisfying, though, if you aren't content with category theory arguments.

Comment: @Randall Yes, I have also read that it can be proven from the properties of $\beta$, rather than from the properties of homeomorphisms. You are pointing at universal property here, right? I would be more satisfied with proving it through the homeomorphisms. Since the $\beta X$ compactification is the "biggest", it seems to me more challenging to check the extensions than if it was only "small" compactification, like Alexandroff, where you just take care of one more point.

Comment: Are you happy with the construction of $\beta X$ as the set of ultrafilters on $X$ (for normal $X$)?

Comment: Yes, that's right:  it's essentially the universality.  I'm sure there is an easy argument along the lines that you'd like, I just haven't thought about S-C in a long time.

Comment: What construction of the Stone-Čech compactification are you using?

Comment: @asdq the construction we use is irrelevant to the question, it’s the universal property that counts. That also shows it’s essentially unique up to homeomorphism so the construction must be irrelevant.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma The OP stated that he wishes not to use the universal property, which implies that he wants an answer to his question that is based on some explicit construction. Hence the question.

Comment: @user10354138 it’s the set of all closed ultrafilters for normal spaces (Walman construction) while for general Tychonoff spaces we need ultrafilters of functionally closed sets instead.

Comment: @asdq I didnt have any particular construction in mind when asking. I am familiar with the construction via closed unit intervals and also via ultrafilters. Why is that important? The $\beta X$ is the same space, no matter how constructed, amirite? I "wish not to use universal property" in the sense that I want to show homeomorphism extension using properties of the homeomorphism itself, not the space on which I try to show that extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the universal mapping property for $\beta X$: we have an embedding $e: X \to \beta X$ and for every continuous map $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ where $Y$ is any compact Hausdorff space there is a *unique* map $\beta f: \beta X\to Y$ which satisfies $\beta f \circ e = f$. If we consider $e$ to be the identity for convenience sake, that just says that $\beta f$ extends $f$ as a map.

If now $h: X \to X$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $h’: X \to X$, then we can consider $h$ to be a map from $X$ to $\beta X$ as well (if we assume $X \subseteq \beta X$, and it’s still continuous, of course. (Being formal, we really mean $e \circ h: X \to \beta X$).

We apply the universal property (as $\beta X$ is compact Hausdorff, we can) and get $\beta h: \beta X \to \beta X$ extending $h$.

Similarly we get $\beta h’:\beta X \to \beta X$ and as $h’ \circ h = 1_X$ and so $\beta h’ \circ \beta h$ extends $1_X$ and by unicity (and the fact that $X$ is dense in $\beta X$) we can conclude that $\beta h’ \circ \beta h = 1_{\beta X}$ and so $\beta h$ is a homeomorphism of $\beta X$ extending $h$.

From an abstract point of view: $X \mapsto \beta X$ is a functor from the category of Tychonoff spaces to the category of compact Hausdorff spaces and as such it preserves isomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question. I understand all you wrote, except "and so $\beta h′$∘$\beta h$ extends $1_X$ and by unicity (and the fact that X is dense in $\beta X$) we can conclude that $\beta h′$∘$\beta h$=$1_{\beta X}$. What is "unicity" and why it implies the composition equals to $1_{\beta X}$?